# Marketplace extensions not available in setup wizard

Tags: extensions, magento2.3.2, marketplace

I have a free `Magento 2.3.2` installation, I have downloaded a free extension on the marketplace I have linked the keys to my setup.

The extension doesn't show available for installation.

I deleted my site and rebuilt it from scratch, I linked the keys again and it showed... then I downloaded another free extension from the marketplace which again isn't showing. I don't wish to rebuild my site every time I want to install an extension.

How can I get this update?

Thanks